# Expressions for exponential map and parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This came up in a paper I was perusing. The authors list three formulas which I have not been able to comprehend. Here M is supposed to be a simply connected space form.

Then for the exponential map along a geodesic $ \gamma_v$ we have:

$$ \exp_p (tv) = f(t)p + g(t)v $$

And the parallel transport is given as :

$$ P^{t}(v)= -\epsilon g(t)p + f(t)v $$

In both the above cases $||v||=1 $ and $v \in T_p (M)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{E}^4$ and:

$ f(t) =1,\ g(t)=t , \ \epsilon =0  $ ; when $ M = \mathbb{E}^3 $

$ f(t) = \cos t ,\ g(t)= \sin t,\ \epsilon = 1 $  ; when $ M = \mathbb{S}^3 $

$ f(t) = \cosh t ,\ g(t)= \sinh t,\ \epsilon = -1 $ ; when $ M = \mathbb{H}^3 $

I realise that the sectional curvature plays a role here.

But can anyone please tell me how one arrives at these expressions?? I am considerably new to the subject and most related expressions I have seen involve Christoffel symbols. If it is explicitly proved in some book, a reference would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the link for the paper :http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/BKMS-50-4-1099-1108.pdf

Sec 3.Page 1101

Comment: The usage of scalar multiplication and addition in $f(t)p+g(t)v$ is puzzling. What do those operations mean for points on a sphere? My guess is that the calculations are done under the assumption that $M$ is embedded into a Euclidean space. Can you confirm or deny?

Comment: Yes, that would be right. An emebedding in an Euclidean space is probably how it is treated. I have edited to include the paper itself. I should have done so earlier, my sincere apologies.

Comment: Can you do at least the case of $M=\mathbb E^3$? The formula simply says that geodesics are straight lines parametrized by length. For the sphere, it says that geodesics are arcs of great circles, also parametrized by length.

Comment: Well yeah I should not have included that.I did get the expression for Euclidean case. I think spherical coordinates would help in the   other case.Is that so??